# gl-shader: Error compiling shader: Compile failed. ERROR: 0:9: 'assign' : cannot convert from '4-component vector

Tags: c++, opengl, expo, react-native, shader

I am trying to write a shader when I can pass both `image saturation value`  like this  https://gl-react-cookbook.surge.sh/saturation?menu=true and `image colorscaling` like this https://gl-react-cookbook.surge.sh/colorscale?menu=true in react native for that I am using opengl in react native. As from the example, I can run both the image saturation and image colorScaling separately but I don't know how to add them together. I am new to opengl i tried reading the docs but could not find any help. Please help me to figure out how to get both the functionality. Here is my Code.

> Error I am getting

```
gl-shader: Error compiling shader:
Compile failed.
ERROR: 0:9: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to '3-component vector of float'
ERROR: 0:12: 'constructor' : too many arguments
ERROR: 0:13: Unexpected syntax error;
ERROR: 3 compilation errors. No code generated.
```

> Shaders

```
const shaders = Shaders.create({
  colorify: {
    frag: GLSL`
    precision highp float;
    varying vec2 uv;
    uniform sampler2D children, colorScale;
    uniform float contrast, saturation, brightness;
    const vec3 L = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    float greyscale (vec3 c) { return 0.2125 * c.r + 0.7154 * c.g + 0.0721 * c.b; }
    void main() {
      vec4 c = texture2D(children, uv);
      vec3 brt = c.rgba * brightness;
      vec4 original = texture2D(children, uv);
      vec4 newcolor = texture2D(colorScale, vec2(greyscale(original.rgb), 0.5));
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vec3(0.5), mix(vec3(dot(brt,L)),brt,saturation),contrast),c.a,newcolor.rgb, original.a * newcolor.a) 
    }
   `,
  },
});




export const Colorify = ({ url, colorScale, interpolation }) => (
  <Node
    shader={shaders.colorify}
    uniformsOptions={{ colorScale: { interpolation } }}
    uniforms={{
      colorScale,
      children: url,
      contrast: 0.3,
      saturation: 0.1,
      brightness: 0.2,
    }}
  />
);



const App = () => {
return (
 <Surface style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill }}>
          <Colorify
            url={route.imageUrl}
            colorScale={colorScales[color]}
            interpolation={interpolation}
          />
        </Surface>)}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *read* the error messages you got:

> ```
> ERROR: 0:9: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to '3-component vector of float'
> ```

So `0:9` here tells us to look into the first string (counting is 0-based here) passed to `glShaderSource`, line 9, which in your code is:

> ```
> vec3 brt = c.rgba * brightness;
> ```

The error is `cannot convert from '4-component vector of float' to '3-component vector of float`. And that is a very descriptive error message. `c.rgba` is a vec4, `vec * float` yields still `vec4`, and you assign this to `vec3 brt`. You need to either:

- store the `vec4` result in a `vec4` variable: `vec4 brt = c.rgba * brightness;`, OR
- explicitly convert the resulting `vec4` to `vec3` : `vec3 brt = vec3(c.rgba * brightness);` or `vec3 brt = (c.rgba * brightness).rgb;` (or whatever components and order you want), OR
- or, and this makes most sense here, do a `vec3` calculation in the first place: `vec3 brt = c.rgb * brightness;`

> ```
> ERROR: 0:12: 'constructor' : too many arguments
> ```

with line 12 being this gem:

> ```
> gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vec3(0.5), mix(vec3(dot(brt,L)),brt,saturation),contrast),c.a,newcolor.rgb, original.a * newcolor.a)
> ```

A `vec4` constructor obviously takes 4 argmuents, but you pass `vec4(vec3, float, vec3, float)`. Which does make totally no sense at all. Your totally got that part of the code wrong. Just read your source materials again.

> ```
> ERROR: 0:13: Unexpected syntax error;
> ```

That's because line 12 also is lacking a `;` at the end, and when the compiler looked for it in the next line, it did not find it, but a `}` instead.